# Tableau, if column > 0 then 1 showing 1's when the column is negative?

Tags: tableau-api

Right now in tableau I have a column showing 1 when another column 'profit-expense' is positive and 0 when 'profit-expense' is negative. Currently it is showing 1's in some of the columns where 'profit-expense' is negative. Has anyone ever experienced this problem before and were able to fix it?

Comment: Can you share the formula used to produce the 1 and 0?

Comment: { FIXED [Sales_Rep]: IF [profit proj - sum tot 90 exp]>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END}

Comment: Is there a good reason to use fixed? That can interfere with filters and produce unexpected results

Comment: So using it without fix does work better. Only problem is on another sheet I am trying to sum the column to show that there are 77 profitable sales reps as a value in a column, but instead it just shows 0.

Comment: Understood. So use the FIXED version on one sheet, and the non-fixed on the other sheet, that work?

Comment: That would work but because the fixed is showing 1s when it should not be the total is messed up and showing 91 profitable reps instead of 77.